# How to call a flex parser in c

Tags: c, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

How to call a flex parser in c ?

Answer (score 7):

By calling `yylex()`.

By default `lex` reads from `stdin`, if you want it to read from other stream, assign `yyin`, like

```
yyin = fopen("myfile", "r");
```

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that yylex is not declared anywhere so you need to declare it:

```
int yylex ();
```

Traditionally it seems that the entire output of lex or flex would be incorporated in the C program via #include.

Recent versions of Flex include an option to create a header file, either on the command line  via the

`--header-file`

option, or in the script

```
%option header-file
```

The header file contains stuff which can be used, for example, to ask Flex to read from memory rather than a file.